# Unity compare if two input fields have same value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I achieve this? A function can take only 1 argument in Unity for an event.
There are two different input fields in the same canvas which I'd like to compare.
I'm assuming this can be done using object as argument but I don't know which object I can pass. I tried dragging the canvas and input field gameObject(I'm guessing that's what it's called) to the object parameter field of my selected function but they don't get accepted.

This is where I want to attach the script:-
[image]

Comment: Where are you dragging to? I'm not familiar with anywhere in Unity you can put a GameObject as an *argument*, only as a field. (Maybe you're referring to some GUI stuff I haven't played with yet, adding clarity to the question would be helpful.)

Comment: @e1eee384 I believe he means he added it as a variable in the inspector

Comment: @e1ee384 I'm tried dragging them to the argument of my method which is called by OnValueChange event of the second input field. I'm using Unity 5. And I'm pretty much sure that's wrong.

Comment: Interesting misreadings of my username! I see now, I just haven't used that UI. Good clarification.

Comment: Oh. That UI is very handy. You should try using it. Though I now prefer using FindWithTag() most of the times :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InputFields are not GameObject. They are objects of UI.InputField class. So in your script import UI with

```
#using UnityEngine.UI;
```

Then create 2 InputField object.

```
public InputField inp1;
public InputField inp2;
```

then drag your InputFields to them. then you can compare their text like that:

```
if( inp1.text == inp2.text) {}
```

Edit: You shouldnt attach a script to there, because the variables may change dynamically. attach this script I have wroten to an empty game object, add new snippet on below to script, and then attach this empty game object to event field that you showed. Then you should select the function will be called when edit ended. For this, create two different function in script for each input field as:

```
//Call this on EndEdit for inputField1
public void InpField1EndEdit()
{
    //compare input fields here or make what you want
}

//Call this on EndEdit for inputField2
public void InpField2EndEdit()
{
    //compare input fields here or make what you want
}
```

Comment: Where should I place this script?

Comment: It doesn't matter. you can place it to an empty game object or main camera.

Comment: I added a screenshot where I want to attach the script. And if I attach it there, I don't see the option where I can drag and drop the input boxes.

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope it solves your problem. By the way sorry for bad English :)

Comment: Thanks, this was useful for future reference. I solved my problem with other method though :)